# Using Laravel helpers in package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-helper

I'm trying to write tests for my laravel package and it depends on Laravel helper dispatch. But package itself don't contains this function.
So I have an error when run tests

Is there a solution for this case? Or should I use DI and inject `Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher` instead of using a helper?

Comment: Can you explain that further? If you depend on a method in a helper package, but that helper packages does not contain that method, where does it come from?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L386) is helper function 
And it often used outside of laravel https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/484ff556fe2def2eab9f8eb2e60becba36c439d9/src/Searchable.php#L66
Some people overide it in test https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/484ff556fe2def2eab9f8eb2e60becba36c439d9/tests/SearchableTest.php#L81

Comment: And how **exactly** does your code look like? Please share some example and the **exact** error message

Comment: My code just call dispatch helper like [this](https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/484ff556fe2def2eab9f8eb2e60becba36c439d9/src/Searchable.php#L66) Error is `function dispatch not found`

Comment: And how do you import these Laravel helpers in your project?

Answer (score -2):

Laravel Testing Helper for Packages Development: https://github.com/orchestral/testbench

Package allows to run tests in laravel-like environment.
You can use database, facades, helpers etc.

> When writing a Laravel application, it generally does not matter if
>   you use contracts or facades since both provide essentially equal
>   levels of testability. However, when writing packages, your package
>   will not typically have access to all of Laravel's testing helpers. If
>   you would like to be able to write your package tests as if they
>   existed inside a typical Laravel application, you may use the
>   Orchestral Testbench package.

Here is example of real usage: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Comment: Please explain that further - don't post links only